# Sweet Alert Confirm - Get user response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sweetalert

I have a JS file where I have a function like this:

```
function eliminarProducto(id){
  var url = '../php/apartado/elimina_producto.php';
  var pregunta = confirm('Are you sure to delete this user?');
```

The message showed in the browser looks simple, so I want to change it by an Sweet Alert message... But I don't know how! ;(

```
if(pregunta==true){
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:url,
    data:'id='+id,
    success: function(registro){
      $('#agrega-registros').html(registro);
      return false;
    }
  });
  return false;
}else{
  return false;
}
```

*********************** EDITED POST ****************************** 
NEW CODE

```
function eliminarProducto(id){
  var url = '../php/apartado/elimina_producto.php';

  swal({
    title: '¡Atención!',
    text: "¿Desea eliminar el registro?",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar'
  }).then(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:url,
      data:'id='+id,
      success: function(registro){
        $('#agrega-registros').html(registro);
      }
    });
  })
}
```

How can I break the action in case if I select the option cancel??? :)

Comment: Strangely unclear... You state knowing how to instantiate a `swal()` via PHP. Then you seem to ask on how to replace a banal `confirm()` into a `swal()`. So... Hey? lol... Can you enlight me?

Comment: Seems more related to Ajax asynchronous response than Swal plugin use or any PHP issue. -- I fixed the tags.

Comment: Okay, let's see, the first code on PHP using sweet alert I wrote it like a reference, because I already know how to do it or how it works. 
But using a function on JS file I don't know how can I make a message using sweet alert like the first one that's why I'm using "confirm" but looks simple. :/ I'm looking for to converting jquery confirm to sweet-alert confirmation, basically.

Comment: Okay.. They quite changed their documentation... Which makes me hard times to find what I had in mind. But look here: https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/#buttons

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it. :) I'm gonna try some things.

Comment: Good... Then please update your question with that attempt, if there is still an issue. And remove the unrelevant PHP. ;) Check the [console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) for any error.

Comment: Ok I understood and got the 50%, It appaers the message and delete the user from my data base but now my question is how to add the rest of code in case if I choose the option cancel? :D
Im gonna add edit the post.

Comment: In addtion, If I choose "cancel" it keeps deleting my data:/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a "swal" working.

How I manage the "confirm" decision is:

```
.catch(swal.noop).then(function(result){...});
```

That "catch" instruction is for the background click OR modal close, mainly. I think it stands for *"No Operation"*, but I'm unsure. It is for whatever else the "OK" or "Not OK" buttons. It catches that and kills it.

So if you actually have a "result" from one of the two buttons, the "then" clause applies.
So `result` is a boolean true/false reflecting user's choice.

Your code would be:

```
function eliminarProducto(id){
  var url = '../php/apartado/elimina_producto.php';

  swal({
    title: '¡Atención!',
    text: "¿Desea eliminar el registro?",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar'
  }).catch(swal.noop).then(function(result){  // Change here.
    if(result){                               // If "yes" from user.
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:url,
        data:'id='+id,
        success: function(registro){
          $('#agrega-registros').html(registro);
        }
      });
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: noop does stand for no operation. :) It's fairly  common in machine language.

Comment: @MustacheMoses: OP speaks Spanish and I'm a native French speaker. So... Since `noop` isn't well defined in Swal docs (And the [new docs](https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/) are cuter but arrg! What the H?), I suppose that this question/answer is relevant... And will be for many. ;)

Comment: I understand your frustration. Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: @MustacheMoses: No frustration here... Just deceptions about the docs... Since I was used to it for a while, since I use the plugin regularly. And it is all new and cuter now, but is (at first look), harder to find infos.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. :) therefore, there's another option I used: swal({title: 'Are you sure?', showCancelButton: true}).then(result => {
  if (result.value) {
    // handle Confirm button click
    // result.value will contain `true` or the input value
  } else {
    // handle dismissals
    // result.dismiss can be 'cancel', 'overlay', 'esc' or 'timer'
  }
}) 

Have a nice day and thanks for youre time.